# Is the notion that the supreme being doesn't touch material energy a Hindu one?

Tags: brahman

Hare Krishnas say that Krishna stays beyond the material plane and interacts with the material world through his "expansions" if I understand correctly.  Does Hindu scripture say anything like this?

Comment: The question is unclear as it stands. Are you asking if scriptures attest whether Brahman is the material cause of the universe or otherwise?

Comment: whether scriptures have a hierarchy of Gods - Gods that touch the material world and the supreme principle that doesn't but acts on the material world through its agents.

Comment: "Prakriti, i.e. the material cause, not only the operative cause, is Brahman only" - [SB 1.4.23](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/sbe48/sbe48165.htm)

Comment: @LakshmiNarayanan Put it as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**No**, that is not a Hindu concept.

God of Hinduism is present everywhere, even in the stones he is there.

See the following Rig Vedic Mantra:

> adrau chidasmA antardurone (1), vishAm na vishvo amrtah swAdhih (2) ||
>
> **Even in the stone he is there for man**, he is there in the middle of
>   his house (1). He is as one universal in creatures; he is the
>   Immortal, the perfect thinker. (2)
>
> **Rig Veda 1.70.4**

Answer (score 5):

God does not actively run the universe. It is primordial Nature, God’s shakti (power) which does everything.

> Resorting to Prakrti, Nature, which is My own Power, I send forth
>   again and again this multitude of beings that are without any freedom,
>   owing to Nature's sway over them.

Gita 9.8

> These activities do not in any way bind Me, **because I remain detached
>   like one unconcerned in their midst.**

Gita 9.9

> Under My direction and control, Nature brings out this mighty universe
>   of living and non-living beings. Thus does the wheel of this world
>   revolve.

Gita 9.10

Comment: please clearly state the conclusion.

Comment: To me the words of Krishna are the words of an avatara.  I am looking for something with more weight.

Comment: @SK he revealed both vishvaroopa of purusha suktam and 4 handed form of narayana suktam, why does his words have less weighteage then? Even brahma sutras refer to gita.